# The command CFLAGS=... make" does not work

Tags: shell, makefile

I tried to compile a C library based on an automatically generated Makefile. The compilation has to add a flag "--coverage" to calculate code coverage.

The command works

```
make CFLAGS=--coverage
```

but not this one

```
CFLAGS=--coverage make
```

This is strange. Any idea why the second one does not work? I am on an Mac terminal which uses zsh if that matters.

Comment: `CFKAGS` in your second attempt instead of `CFLAGS`?

Comment: typo corrected. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not strange.  We can't say for sure because you didn't tell us how `CFLAGS` is set in your makefile, but you likely have something like this:

```
CFLAGS = -g -O2
```

Variable assignments on the command line take precedence over variable assignments in the makefile.  But variable assignments in the makefile take precedence over variables imported from the environment.

The [GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Using-Variables.html) describes this.

Comment: What does "CFLAGS = -g -O2" have to do with where it needs to be put on the command line?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  What I'm saying is that somewhere in your makefile (which you haven't shown us) is an assignment of the variables `CFLAGS`.  We don't know what it is exactly, because you haven't shown us, so I just made one that is a typical assignment one might find in a typical makefile.  Maybe yours is different, we can't know that.  But, assignments in the makefile will override assignments from the environment.

Comment: Maybe the problem is you don't know what the difference is between the commands `make FOO=bar` and `FOO=bar make`?  This is a shell question not a make question.  In the shell if you write `FOO=bar xxx` then this will assign the environment variable `FOO` to the value `bar` while it runs the command `xxx`, but only for that command.  It's kind of equivalent to `oldFOO=$FOO; export FOO=bar; xxx; FOO=$oldFOO; unset oldFOO` except it works properly if `FOO` was not set at all as well.

Comment: I see! So make FOO=bar actually sets the file like *in* Makefile, which therefore overwrites the ones already in Makefile. Right?

Comment: I suppose... I wouldn't say it like that because it seems confusing.  Certainly the makefile itself (the file on disk) is not overwritten!  The manual sections above describe the behavior, but simplified: when make starts all exported shell environment variables are imported as make variables, then makefiles are parsed and variable assignments there override the environment variables, and command line variables override assignments in the makefile.

Comment: The key is that `FOO=bar make` and `make FOO=bar` are fundamentally different (in UNIX you can't just rearrange the command line arbitrarily: order matters in some, but not all, situations).  In `FOO=bar make`, the _shell_ handles the variable assignment (to a shell variable) and the `make` program never even sees the argument.  In `make FOO=bar`, the shell invokes `make` with a `FOO=bar` command line argument and it's up to make to decide how to handle it.